# how to escape from non array key in json?

Tags: javascript, object

My code collects sell values. When i run my code, it breaks because there's date key in the first line which it doesnt count as array. When i deleted the date key, it works but date key must be stay there; i cant change the json.

```
let data = {
  Update_Date: "2023-03-15 14:00:01",
  USD: {
    Come: "18,9814",
    Type: "Currency",
    Sell: "18,9839",
    Change: "%0,04",
  },
  EUR: {
    Come: "20,1690",
    Type: "Currency",
    Sell: "20,1777",
    Change: "%-0,94",
  }
};
```

---

```
let t=0;
for (key in data) {
  if(data[key] != "Update_Date"){
    parseInt(data[key].Sell);
    const sell1=parseFloat(String(data[key].Sell).replace(",","."));
    t+=sell1;
    console.log(toplam);
  }
}
```

I have tried, !=, data.key instanceof Array == true for escape but it doesnt work. What can i do?

Comment: There are no arrays in your data. What do you mean by "doesn't count as array"? The value of `Update_date` is a string, the other values are objects.

Comment: `if(data[key] != "Update_Date")` should be `if (key != "Update_Date")`

Comment: thank you @Barmar   thanks for correcting me, yes i need to get sell keys from objects but code stucks at that string so it doesnt works. i tried if (key != "Update_Date") but didnt work as well.

Comment: What is `toplam`?

Comment: It works for me, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing the value, not the key.

Change `data[key]` to `key` in the `if` statement.

```js
let data = {
  Update_Date: "2023-03-15 14:00:01",
  USD: {
    Come: "18,9814",
    Type: "Currency",
    Sell: "18,9839",
    Change: "%0,04",
  },
  EUR: {
    Come: "20,1690",
    Type: "Currency",
    Sell: "20,1777",
    Change: "%-0,94",
  }
};

let t = 0;
for (key in data) {
  if(key != "Update_Date"){
    const sell1 = parseFloat(data[key].Sell.replace(",","."));
    t += sell1;
  }
}
console.log(t);
```

Comment: thank you so much i love you